# soundpool.play is not playing sound

Tags: android

I have the following code to play a sound, it is in the `onsurfacecreated` method of an `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` class

```
SoundPool pool=new SoundPool(20,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
int resourceID=_context.getResources().getIdentifier("collisionsound","raw","com.frd.neongameengine");
int id=pool.load(_context,resourceID,1);
try {
    Thread.sleep(20000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
int status=pool.play(id,1,1,0,0,1);
```

however it does not play a sound and `soundpool.play` returns 0....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You code looks fine, except redundant `Thread.sleep` and strange way of retrieving resource id (you don't need to call `getIdentifier`, you can just load your sound with `load(_context, R.raw.collisionsound`). Do you have any errors in Logcat? Maybe your file is too big for `SoundPool` and you should user `MediaPlayer` instead.

Comment: I am using getIdentifier as I need to iterate through a config file loading the sounds as I go. The thread.sleep is there to make sure the sound file is loaded by the time it is played as that has been noted as an issue on many answers I have found. The sound file is 11kb so it is pretty small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue.

There appears to be something soundpool did not like with my wav file (it was a windows system sound). It played fine in all my media players but as soon as I converted it to an mp3 it worked fine....

So although I say I have found the issue, I suppose I have just found a work around rather than knowing why a file that plays fine everywhere else does not play through soundpool.